# Copying (usb drive to usb drive) suddenly slowed down. Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, clipboard, mediatomb

I just got an old computer from a friend and I am using it as a mediatomb server. Because the computers hard drives are rather small and I don't have the money for newer ones I am temporarily using 2 usb drives to store all the media.

I am currently in the progress of transferring all my media files from my three other computers to these 2 drives using a third. Until yesterday this all went smoothly, but since this afternoon, when I started a new 'batch' of copying my copying speed suddenly dropped to app. 0.4MB/S (according to nautilus)

To clarify: I didn't touch the computer between finishing the last copying task, disconnecting the drive, copying files from another computer onto it, reconnecting it and starting to copy again.

Also, rebooting and disabling mediatomb have had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165993/really-slow-copy-speed) which suggested it might have something to do with automounting the drives. I disabled the `usbmount` package which I use to automount the USB drives at boot and mounted them in the terminal. It worked!